# Ngnix is not serving my ejs view tempaltes but they are working locally

Tags: javascript, node.js, nginx, ejs

I had recently deployed my node and express website on the ubuntu LTS 22.04 on linode.
I am using Nginx and  for serving my files.
I had just edited my default file to run my application here the code for it

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }
}
```

these are the changes that i made their

->here the of my index.js

```
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"));
app.use(passport.session());
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
initializePassport(passport);
```

and route on which i am serving my template

```
app.get("/login", (req, res) => {
res.render("login");
});
```

all these things are workign locally and even on the production my apis are working but not serving any of my view template

[Here is the image of my folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NPgp.png)

I tried changing some url in the
`app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views")); app.use(passport.session()); app.set("view engine", "ejs"); initializePassport(passport);`

like adding / and also go through some blogs

Comment: "but not serving any of my view template" — What does this mean? Does the request time out? Do you get an unexpected HTTP status code on the response?

Comment: If you add `console.log` statements to the routes that handle the EJS, do they get output?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Yes if you add the console.log it provides output. But the only problem is while rendering templates

Comment: Even If I try to access the protected routes it redirects me to login page